# Can I detect when an Apple TV app becomes active again from TVJS?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I need to take an action whenever my TVML/TVJS Apple TV app becomes active again after having already been launched. It seems the [`onLaunch` app lifecycle event](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSApplication_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/App) is only called when my app is launched from scratch. Is this possible using TVJS or do I have to use `evaluateInJavaScriptContext` in the `applicationDidBecomeActive` method in my `AppDelegate`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's [currently undocumented](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSApplication_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/javascript/cl/App) but the `App.onResume` property seems to work in tvOS beta 3.

```
App.onResume = function (options) {
  console.log("App resumed.");
  console.log(options);
};
```

Comment: Were you trying to get the app to reload data? Did you try the App.reload method? It doesn't seem to be working for me on the final release. Either that or the onResume is not firing at all.